# How to (dis) associate an application from starting when a CD is inserted to the computer (Win XP)

Tags: windows-xp, optical-drive

I put a CD in my laptop and Nokia Music Manager now pops up.  I want to disable that.

I went to the settings in the Nokia Music Manager and unchecked the box that said for it to open up when a CD was inserted.  This setting appears to be persistent (i.e. it is still unchecked when the application starts the next time I put a CD in).

I tried the file associations in the Folder Options in the control panel, but nothing stood out there.

XP SP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, figured it out.

- RMB on the CD drive under 'My Computer', Properties
- Select the 'Autoplay' tab
- Go through each content type, selecting 'Take No Action'

In my particular case it was the association for 'Music Files'